# Is there a more efficient way to quickly edit many variables with corresponding values from a table in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, variable-assignment

Here is my current code snippet, without posting all the other information, assume that everything works correctly. There is nothing wrong with the code. As an example, I am reading a text document with Grabber, a Scanner object, with one line of text that will look like this:
`5,4,6,1,10,10,10,10,0,0,0,0,`
There will never be more or less than 12 numbers on this first line, so there will never be an issue with out of bounds. Also, all variables getting an integer value are int types.

```
String[] Grabbed_Line = Grabber.nextLine().split(","); 
Wins = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[0]);
Losses = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[1]);
Ties = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[2]);
TrueTies = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[3]);
P1Wins = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[4]);
P1Losses = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[5]);
P1Ties = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[6]);
P1TrueTies = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[7]);
P2Wins = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[8]);
P2Losses = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[9]);
P2Ties = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[10]);
P2TrueTies = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[11]);
```

Ideally, I'd rather put all these variables into a table/array/arraylist and use a for statement to assign them, something like

```
String[] Grabbed_Line = Grabber.nextLine().split(","); 
int[] Vars = {Wins,Losses,Ties,TrueTies,P1Wins,P1Losses,P1Ties,P1TrueTies,P2Wins,P2Losses,P2Ties,P2TrueTies};
for(int Counter = 0; Counter < 12; Counter++)
      Vars[Counter] = Integer.parseInt(Grabbed_Line[Counter]);
```

Obviously, I know this wouldn't work (I mean it would but not in the way I want); I'm just passing int values into a table, it's not going to actually affect the variables. In C++, I'd use pointers and addresses to do something like this, but from what I've read, Java doesn't do this. I guess it'd be different if they were references and not primitives, buuuut I'm not sure how to go about this because I'm dumb.

One thing I would have liked to try would have been to reference the variables by strings, as dumb as that sounds. I know some languages, tables/arrays can have strings as indexes, so I'd be able to do that. Now that I think about it, does ArrayList support that? No, it doesn't look like it does. I could cheat by making an array of 12 integers at the beginning, and any time I would have normally changed one of those variables, I could just change the appropriate spot in the array, but then it would have become confusing to remember which index corresponds to what I want to save, like

```
int[12] Multiple_Vars; // Initialized at the beginning
for(int Counter=0;Counter<12;Counter++)
     Multiple_Vars[Counter] = 0;
...
... // later on in the code somewhere
if(Your_Attack>Their_Defense)
     Multiple_Vars[7]+=1; // Was it the 8th or 3rd index that keeps track of points?
...
...
```

Am I missing something obvious or am I just going to have to bite the bullet and edit all the variables like the way I described in the beginning? I guess I could technically save typing space by making a function to save time on typing Integer.parseInt() over and over, but other than that, I can't think of any way.

Comment: You could just do `int[] Vars = new int[12];`. Or do you want the variable names also? In that case using a CSV reader can potentially save some typing.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to keep the variable names for readability purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fleshing out @Sweeper's comment:

```
final int WINS = 0;
final int LOSSES = 1;
final int TIES = 2;
final int TRUE_TIES = 3;
final int P1_WINS = 4;
final int P1_LOSSES = 5;
final int P1_TIES = 6;
final int P1_TRUE_TIES = 7;
final int P2_WINS = 8;
final int P2_LOSSES = 9;
final int P2_TIES = 10;
final int P2_TRUE_TIES = 11;

String[] grabbedLine = grabber.nextLine().split(",");
for (int i = WINS; i <= P2_TRUE_TIES; i++) {
    scores[i] = Integer.parseInt(grabbedLine[i]);
}
```

Or you could use a `Map` with either `int` values (`WINS`, `LOSSES`, etc) as above) or `String` values (`"wins"`, `"losses"`, etc) as the keys.

Finally, if the CSV's first row gives the column name (or even not), you could do something clever with reflection, assuming that the variables are actually object fields.

But there is no good way to put each score into a distinct (local) Java variable in the way you envisaged.  And you can't do C / C++ tricks like incrementing the addresses of variables.

---

If your criterion for efficiency is CPU time or Memory used, then your original approach cannot be improved on. AFAIK.

Comment: Whoops, while writing out how I didn't understand what you meant, I started to understand what you meant. While that for statement is a bit odd and I think it has a typo, I get what you're saying. Instead of using a String as an index, using a int variable that's NAMED what I want it to be with a matching value to point to the right index, so I could use Scores[TrueTies], as an example, and it would be easy to understand at a quick glance. I think I'll go with this approach. Also, thank you for bringing up Maps, I think I'll be learning that next.

Comment: Yea ... there was a typo.  Fixed it.

Comment: I also fixed some style errors ...

Comment: Also, I had no idea what a CSV was, I ended up on commas because whitespace separated made it confusing to read with my eyes and my preferred symbol | wasn't being split apart correctly by the string function, so thanks for bringing that up as well.